# Integrating a symbolic expression with differentials in the equation

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, integral

I have the following simple ODE:

[image]

How can I symbolically solve for T(t)? I would prefer to solve for dT and then integrate both sides.

The SymPy equation that I have for dT at this point is:

[image]

Note the dT is in the expression.

Comment: You can use `dsolve`.

Comment: I am struggling with dsolve() to get the result I want.

Comment: Please share your current sympy code.